# Add multiple files with onChange function and React Hooks, but singly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, react-hooks

I need to add to files with react components. Here how I'm doing it with one file(onChange and onSubmit functions):

```
const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
  };

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItem = new FormData();
    newItem.append('item', fileData);

    const { description } = offerData;

    newItem.append('description', description);

    addItem(newItem);

    setFileData(null);
  }
```

Input(reactstrap):

```
<CustomInput
     type="file"
     name="item" id="item" label="Choose item image..."
     onChange={onChangeFile}
/>
```

And here, how I'm doing it with multiple files, but with one input:

```
const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFileData(e.target.files);
  };

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = new FormData();
    for (const key of Object.keys(fileData)) {
      newItem.append('item', fileData[key])
    }

    const { description1, description2 } = item;

    newItem.append('description1', description1);
    newItem.append('description2', description2);

    addItem(newItem);
    setFileData(null);
  }
```

and input:

```
<CustomInput
     type="file"
     name="item"
     id="item"
     multiple
     label="Add images/image..."
     onChange={onChangeFile}
/>
```

And both works, but this time I want to add multiple files( two exactly), with two single inputs and my useState hook doesn't work(like that it isn't iterable). Here's how it looks like for both ways.

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(null);
```

So, how to add one object with two images, but added with two single inputs?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I fully understand. So the way you have it now you have a single input to receive data, however you want to be able to update your state from two inputs?

When you are setting state you are doing:

```
const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFileData(e.target.files);
};
```

If this same handler is hooked up to another input, the second set of files will just override the first.

If you want to keep adding to your state you could either use an object, or an array. So onChange could look something like this:

```
const onChangeFile = e => {
    // assuming here that e.target.files is an array already
    const filesToAdd = e.target.files;
    setFileData([...filesData, ...filesToAdd]);
};
```

Or with an object

```
const onChangeFile = e => {
    const filesToAdd = e.target.files.reduce(
                         (map, file) => ({..., [file.name]: file}), {}));
    const filesDataUpdate = {
         ...filesData,
         ...filesToAdd
    }
    setFileData(filesDataUpdate);
};
```

In this case I am assuming each file has a unique name. You could key it with any unique value.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I found the solution. I just created two useState hooks. And then i created array with these two hooks data. arrayData=[data1, data2]. I'll check your solution later.